# Okay to delete MININT folder?

Tags: windows-10

I have a desktop machine running Windows 10 home edition, a few months old. I noticed there is a folder called MININT in C:\, which contains a few dozen files, of unclear purpose that look like they might be installation logs. A Google search suggests this folder is left over from the installation of *something* - exactly what, I'm not clear about - and was supposed to be automatically deleted, but sometimes isn't.

Is it okay for me to just delete it manually?

Comment: The folder in question is created from SCCM (Microsoft System Center Configuration Manager) and Microsoft Deployment Toolkit.  You should ask your IT Administrator if the folder is safe to delete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can delete it. That file was created due MDT deployment which wasn't successful finished.

Comment: With a source, this post would be helpful.